# applications connect to oracle scan ip

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c, rac

I have an Oracle 19c RAC cluster that contains two nodes (say, Node A and Node B). My applications are connected to the SCAN IP along with the service handled by Node A. Is this a good practice, or should they connect only to the SCAN IP and let it take care of load balancing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All connections should go to the Scan IP addresses, as these are highly available (essentially the whole point of RAC). The service can be configured to run on one node and fail over to the other if necessary, or can run on both nodes so that no failover is required (less downtime to reconnect if there's a failure). In general it is best to run all services on all nodes unless you have a specific workload isolation issue or a monitoring connection that needs to be node-specific.